# Rails displaying images from a belongs_to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to display multiple images for a a car from a separate linked table, i have the both models sorted with the belongs_to and has_many but on the main car page i need to show images from the linked table that have the same id.

here is the current code:-

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>


<h2>
  <em><%= @car.make.make_name %> <%= @car.model %> <%= @car.body_typw %> <%= @car.engine_size %> <%= @car.trim %></em>
</h2>

<p>
  <%= image_tag @car.image(:large) %>
</p>

<% @carimages.each do |carimage| %>

    <%= image_tag carimage.image(:thumb), :class => "imgsmall" %>

<% end %>

<p>
  <b>Transmission:</b>
  <%= @car.transmission %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Fuel type:</b>
  <%= @car.fuel_type %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Millage:</b>
  <%= @car.millage %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Price:</b>
  <%= number_to_currency(@car.price) %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= raw @car.content %>
</p>

<p style="font-size:16px;"><b>Call us now on <span style="color:red;">01446 746 785</span> to find out more about the <%= @car.model %> <%= @car.body_typw %> <%= @car.engine_size %> <%= @car.trim %></b></p>
```

so basically the url is - http://localhost:3000/cars/1 and i want the car images with the linked id of car_id of 1 to be shown.

Robbie

Comment: If you have the belongs_to set up correctly and the columns in the DB are correct, just do @car.carimages.each do |image|...

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, and my models seem to be correct, would - @car.carimages.each do |image| relate to the ID through association?

Comment: i have this in my cars_controller also-


 @carimages = Carimage.find(:all, :limit => 10, :order => "id DESC")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
<% @car.carimages.each do |carimage| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your car images table is named 'carimages' and you have the right belongs_to association in this table, and has_many in you 'cars' table, you can always call

```
@car.images.each do |image|
```

to get all the images linked whit you @car

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, and my models seem to be correct, would - @car.carimages.each do |image| relate to the ID through association?

Comment: Do you have a working association through your models? Try to open a Rails Console ("rails c" on prompt) and try `c=Car.new` and then `c.carimages`. If you get an error, there's some problem with your association

Comment: thanks for the advice, all working now using - <% @car.carimages.each do |carimage| %>